# How to turn lumia 925 on/off when screen lock doesn't work?

Tags: lock-screen, lumia-925

My lock screen button on my Lumia 925 stopped working recently. Unfortunately I need to restart it quite often so I would need an alternative way of turning it off. Anyone knows how to restart it without using the lock screen button or a way on how to fix it?